# Android Studio Google Map Eiffel Tower Place Type

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am making an application which shows the nearby places of a given location. I take the location name and place types like museum,place of worship est. from the user and show the locations from that given type.

My problem is, I can't get some special places like Eiffel Tower because there is no such type. How can I get these kind of places ?

And these are the supported types: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

Answer (score 0):

You probably use [Nearby Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests), try [Text Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) with query=attractions instead and don't forget to specify location and radius.